# Trying to modify a string with a button click event

Tags: python, tkinter

So i have coded a keyboard in tkinter, and i am trying to create a game where the user has to click the key corresponding to the displayed character. Once they click the correct key the character changes to another character. I want to have a certain number of characters that once the user has clicked them all they win.

At the moment I have the code working so when they click they right key the character changes. But i cant seem to work out how to keep track of when they have finished clicking all the right keys.

All the keys have this command

```
new_but = Button(button_frame, text=key, command=lambda x=key: letter_check(x,target))
```

and here is the code for the command

```
def clear_data(String):
    String.set("")

def show_data(string):
    data.set(string)

def letter_check(string, target):
    if data.get() == string:
        data.set("")

    target = next_target(target)

def next_target(block):
    new_block = list(block)
    letter = random.choice(new_block)
    new_block.remove(letter)
    show_data(letter)
    block = str(new_block)
    print(new_block)
    return block

target = "abcdef"
n = 3
```

where the show_data and clear_data methods just change the display character. I know that in the command I​ am always going to be using the original target string "abcdef"

I want it to work so at the start I have the target string "abcdef", then the system will randomly pick one of the character in the target string say it chooses "b" then I want the target string to now be "acdef" then when the corresponding key ('b') is clicked, again it chooses another random char say "e" then the target string should be "acdf" and so on until the target string is empty then the game is won. I just don't know how to keep track of the modified target string in the methods. I am fairly new to tkinter so not sure if I can have a "main" method to keep track of everything? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why not add the pressed letters to a list? When you select the next random letter, perform a check to see if the new letter exists in the list already.

Comment: Each button click creates a new instance of the method so how could i keep track of a list if every click resets the list

Comment: You can define `target` as `list` instead of `string`. Also no need to create `new_block` from `block` inside `next_target(..)` function, just remove `letter` from `block`.